# Update intermediate rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I have a data set like this:

```
Date                    ID
2015-06-17 15:57:00.000 1
NULL                    2
NULL                    3
NULL                    4
NULL                    5
NULL                    6
2015-06-17 15:58:00.000 7
NULL                    8
NULL                    9
NULL                    10
NULL                    11
NULL                    12
2015-06-17 17:50:04.000 13
NULL                    14
2015-06-17 17:51:00.000 16
NULL                    17
2015-06-17 17:52:03.000 19
NULL                    20
2015-06-17 17:52:04.000 22
NULL                    23
2015-06-17 17:52:04.000 25
NULL                    26
2015-06-17 17:52:04.000 28
NULL                    29
```

As you can see, they are in sequence (ascending), but many dates are NULL

I want to update the NULL entries to have the nearest prior date/time

So rows 2 thru 6 should get the date time from row ID 1 and 
8 thru 12 should get datetime from ID 7, etc.

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this with a single update statement, but I'd drawing a blank

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: If a higher id has a lower date (say 1 - Jun 17, 2 - Jun 16, 3 - NULL), which date do you want the 3 to have?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use a correlated subquery to do this; the following query seemed to work when I tried it (see fiddle below), but be sure to have a backup handy in case I'm wrong :-)

```
update t1
set date = (select max(date) from your_table where id <= t1.id and date is not null)
from your_table t1
where t1.date is null
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7791e/1)

Note that this might give some strange results if the dates aren't sequential which I assumed they are.

Also, if you're using a version 2012+ of SQL Server then using the `max()` function as a windowed function (`max(date) over (...)`) is a better option. The details are presented in another answer.

Comment: `where t1.date is null`?

Comment: Two things I would add: One, add brackets around the column [date] because it's a keyword. Two, add "AND [date] IS NOT NULL" in your subquery to get rid of the warning message.

Comment: @Habo - worked great. (Actually ended up figuring it out myself and came up with exactly same result.) I'm just updating a few thousand rows and it's for log analysis when we have issues, so performance isn't much of an issue

Comment: cursor probably. A window function approach is here http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/last-non-null-puzzle

Comment: It would be possible to use a quirky update approach similar to running totals but that is  not a "safe" solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MAX() OVER() effectively here

```
Update table1 
    set t1.date = t2.date
    From 
          table1 t1
          INNER JOIN (Select id, max(date) over(order by id) date from table1)    t2
          ON t1.id = t2.id
```

[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/329731)

As  Quassnoi [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081721/update-intermediate-rows/31082208?noredirect=1#comment50182739_31082208) this depends on the dates being non-descreasing.

Martin Smith [contens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31081721/update-intermediate-rows/31082208?noredirect=1#comment50182759_31082208) that this formulation is better

```
WITH CTE AS (
       Select *, 
              max(Date) over(order by ID) AS newdate 
       from table1) 
UPDATE CTE 
SET Date = newdate
```

Comment: this assumes dates are non-decreasing

Comment: You don't need the self join BTW.  `WITH CTE AS (Select *, max(Date) over(order by ID) AS newdate from table1)  UPDATE CTE set Date = newdate` is more efficient.

Comment: @MartinSmith ok. I've updated the answer to include that .

Comment: @jpw - 2012+ previous versions don't support order by in windowed aggregates.

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh right; I misread the MSDN docs on that and didn't notice that there was a difference between ranking and aggregate functions. I guess I'll go sleep instead of doing this ;)

Answer (score 1):

In 2012 and above:

```
WITH    s AS
        (
        SELECT  id, date,
                COALESCE(
                        LEAD(id) OVER (ORDER BY id),
                        (
                        SELECT  MAX(id) + 1
                        FROM    t
                        )
                ) nid
        FROM    t
        WHERE   date IS NOT NULL
        )
MERGE
INTO    t
USING   s
ON      t.id > s.id
        AND t.id < s.nid
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     date = s.date
;
```

This still has to read the whole table twice, but does it in a more efficient way than a nested loop for each record over and over, especially if the gaps are large.

Earlier versions:

```
UPDATE  m
FROM    mytable m
SET     date =
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1
                date
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.id < m.id
                AND mi.date IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY
                id DESC
        )
WHERE   date IS NULL
```

Comment: @MartinSmith: you're right, for some reason I thought `LAST_VALUE` ignored NULLs

Answer (score 0):

```
    Drop Table T1
GO
Create table T1( MyDate DateTime, Id int );

Insert T1 Values
('2015-06-17 15:57:00.000',  1),
(NULL, 2), 
(NULL, 3), 
(NULL, 4), 
(NULL, 5), 
(NULL, 6), 
('2015-06-17 15:58:00.000', 7), 
(NULL, 8), 
(NULL, 9), 
(NULL, 10), 
(NULL, 11), 
(NULL, 12), 
('2015-06-17 17:50:04.000', 13), 
(NULL, 14), 
('2015-06-17 17:51:00.000', 16), 
(NULL, 17), 
('2015-06-17 17:52:03.000', 19), 
(NULL, 20), 
('2015-06-17 17:52:04.000', 22), 
(NULL, 23), 
('2015-06-17 17:52:04.000', 25), 
(NULL, 26), 
('2015-06-17 17:52:04.000', 28), 
(NULL, 29) ;

SELECT 
    A.MyDate,b.LastDate, A.Id
FROM T1 A
CROSS APPLY( 
            Select Top 1 MyDate as LastDate  
            From T1 
            where Id <= A.Id and Mydate is not null
            order by id desc   
            ) B
```